# Create user for all databases in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, security

How can I create a user and grant it read-only access for all databases available in MongoDB (2.2/2.4/2.6) instance?

I am new to MongoDB, please provide the detailed, step-by-step process.

Comment: What did you try so far? SO is not a "do your work" service.

Comment: The range of MongoDB server versions mentioned all reached end of life 5-7 years ago. I would strongly recommend upgrading to a modern version of MongoDB as there have been many improvements to security, stability, and performance (with 9 major release series since 2.2). However, as others have noted you can find auth information in the relevant version of the MongoDB documentation. MongoDB 2.2 and 2.4 predated Role-Based Access Control, which was introduced in 2.6 and evolved in successive releases. Since you are new to MongoDB, I would recommend starting with the current 4.4 release.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to enable **authorization**, and create the user with the `readAnyDatabase` access for the MongoDB v2.4 deployment.

- [Enable
  Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/enable-authentication/)
- [Create a User   Administrator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/add-user-administrator/)
- [Add a User to a Database](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/add-user-to-database/) - in this step, create a user with read-only access for all databases with the role [readAnyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/#readAnyDatabase) - this role provides users with the ability to read data from any collection, from all logical databases in the MongoDB environment.

As an example, you can try the following **tutorial** from MongoDB v4.2 documentation. This tutorial [Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/enable-authentication/) steps are the similar to that of the version 2.4 you want to work with. Note that, some commands, like `createUser` is `addUser`in v2.4, have different syntax - please be mindful of that.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to any one of recent MongoDB versions and then it's very easy follow the below steps:

1. Enable authentication on the `/etc/mongod.conf` file

> ```
>  security:
>         authorization: enabled
> ```

2. Create a read user on `admin DB`, since you want to access all DBs. If specific DB then create on that specific db

> ```
> use admin
> ```

> ```
>    db.createUser(   
>     {
>     user: "read_admin",
>      pwd: "yourpassword", 
>     roles: [ { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]  
>      } )
> ```

3. Restart the MongoDB service

> ```
> sudo service mongod restart
> ```

4. Login into the mongo shell and check the user

> ```
> mongo -u read_admin --authenticationDatabase admin
> ```